# Problem in creating 100% stacked bar chart for 2 different metrics

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

Recently I've met a problem while I have been working on a project. Briefly I need to draw a 100% stacked bar chart for 2 different metrics which are *the number of outlets* (customers) and *the sales of those outlets* in 3 classification. Therefore, I need to use 2 y-axis in order to illustrate those two separately. However, I would like to show absolute value of data label instead of the relative percentage. And the problem shows off since the value of the two metrics are in different range, which cause the labels to lay on a wrong position.

1. I used facet_wrap to separate the two metrics into 2 facets for illustration.
2. By using position = "fill", I could be able to show absolute value instead of calculating ration (fall between 0 and 1).
3. Using position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5) enable me to align the data label into center of the bar chart. However it only works smoothly for 1 metrics.

```
dt_4_slide1_long_test %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = value, fill = OutletClassification, label = value))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity")+
  facet_wrap(~variable)+
  ggtitle("Sales and Outlet Proportion by Channel")+
  geom_text(aes(
              x = month, 
              y = ave(value, month, FUN = function(x) (cumsum(x) - 0.5 * x) / sum(x)),
              label = value
            ),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            size = 2
            )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=8),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

So, my expectation is that I could show absolute value of the 2 metrics, which is aligned to the center of the bar chart.

[image: Sample of my chart]

And here is sample data
[Sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CtVTooTwFLyLlcpTv022zbPXLPJY45zO/view?usp=sharing)

Or may this sample data would help:

```
structure(list(month = c("2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-06", 
"2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-06", 
"2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-06", 
"2019-07", "2019-08"), OutletClassification = c("0010102_Lẻ đường phố", 
"0010102_Lẻ đường phố", "0010102_Lẻ đường phố", 
"0010401_Chạp phô", "0010401_Chạp phô", "0010401_Chạp phô", 
"0010402_Lẻ chợ", "0010402_Lẻ chợ", "0010402_Lẻ chợ", 
"0010102_Lẻ đường phố", "0010102_Lẻ đường phố", 
"0010102_Lẻ đường phố", "0010401_Chạp phô", "0010401_Chạp phô", 
"0010401_Chạp phô", "0010402_Lẻ chợ", "0010402_Lẻ chợ", 
"0010402_Lẻ chợ"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no_customer", 
"total_sales"), class = "factor"), value = c(29, 30, 26, 18, 
16, 15, 109, 109, 101, 234.062, 248.07, 195.67, 34.415, 28.077, 
36.29, 618.741, 543.843, 474.76)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide your data in a easy, reproducible format (e.g. using `dput()`).

Comment: yeah I used dput() and have already input the data in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position_fill(vjust = 0.5)`. `df` is the data you posted.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = value, fill = OutletClassification, label = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  ggtitle("Sales and Outlet Proportion by Channel") +
  geom_text(position  = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 2) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=8),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]